# SAS max function result

Tags: sas

Had a look at SAS documentation and around SO, but being a bit distant from the field and SAS specifically, wanted to ask for help.
I am looking at some SAS code, where this specific part is of interest:

```
  SELECT A.*,
         CASE WHEN A.all_111 > max(99.99, 0.025*AMOUNT)
```

This runs before a table of entries is created. The table is supposed to discard values below 100. I am presuming that's what the first argument (99.99) in max does.
However, I am not sure what is the purpose of 0.025*AMOUNT?

Comment: your code is not completely clear as ; ends the proc sql

Comment: I changed the `&gt;` to which is likely a `>` sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max simply takes the maximum of 99.99 and 0.025* amount, which is 2.5% of the amount. So if 2.5% of the amount is more than 100 then it can be higher than 100. Max would be operating on each individual row value here.